# Using pexpect to automate IP validations

Tags: python, ssh, network-programming, pexpect, switching

My end goal is to log into a switch, get the CDP neighbor details written to a file. parse out the IP addresses and run pings on the IP address and output that to a file. I've searched the forums and found nothing really pertaining to switches. Mainly servers, and I've adapted from there. But Now I am stuck.

I get as far as getting logged into a switch and my login prompts seem to be written to a file but nothing else.

Please excuse errors in the code. Also, the second try block is a work in progress. I am new to python and learning as I go. I am open to any and all critiques and suggestions. I want to know what I have done incorrectly, fix it, and build from there.

Thanks in advance!

```
import pexpect
import getpass
import sys
import re
import os
import time


try:
    switch = raw_input("Host: ")
    un = raw_input("Username: ")
    pw = getpass.getpass("Password: ")

    options = '-q -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -oUserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -oPubkeyAuthentication=no'
    prompt = "#"


    connection_string = ("ssh %s@%s %s" % (un,switch,options))


    child = pexpect.spawn(connection_string, timeout=5)
    file_output = open('switch_output.txt','wb+')
    child.logfile = file_output
    rva12 = "";

    child.expect(re.escape("password:"))
    time.sleep(1)
    child.sendline(pw)
    time.sleep(1)
    child.expect(prompt)
    time.sleep(1)
    child.sendline("no page")
    time.sleep(1)
    child.expect(prompt)
    child.sendline("show cdp nei det")
    time.sleep(1)
    child.expect(prompt)
    child.before

    file_output.close()

except Exception as e:
    print("Failed on login")
    print(sys.exc_info()[0].__name__,
          os.path.basename(sys.exc_info()[2].tb_frame.f_code.co_filename),
          sys.exc_info()[2].tb_lineno)
    print(e)


try:
    f = open('switch_output.txt', 'r')
    pattern_one = re.compile('.*A\d\n|\:\s\d{2,}\.\d{2,}\.\d{1,}.\d{1,}?')

    for line in f:
        matches = []

        if pattern_one.search(line):
        matches.append(line.split(':', 1)[-1].strip())

        mp = re.compile('\d{2,}\.\d{2,}\.\d{1,}.\d{1,}')

        with open('MDF1.txt', 'wb+') as file:
            for match in matches:
                if mp.search(match):
                    file.write(match+'\n')
                    file.close()

        for line in open('MDF1.txt','r'):
            child.expect(prompt)
            child.sendline('ping '+ line)
            time.sleep(10)


except Exception as e:
    print(sys.exc_info()[0].__name__,
        os.path.basename(sys.exc_info()[2].tb_frame.f_code.co_filename),
        sys.exc_info()[2].tb_lineno)
    print(e)
```

Comment: Just speculating (and it's been quite a long time since I used `pexpect`) but at a glance, I'm skeptical of your `prompt` definition. At a minimum, won't you want it anchored at the beginning of the line?  `"^#"`

Comment: The only other advice I can offer is that it's often better to start *without* a try-except. That way, if you get an exception, the interpreter shows you exactly where you went wrong (and can use `pdb` to diagnose). Then, once the basic logic is working, you can put try-except back in to intelligently recover from error conditions. As is, you can't distinguish between login failing and any other `expect` failure.

Comment: @GilHamilton I appreciate your response. I will take a look into both of your suggestions.